# Log out of facebook automatically if logged in

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

I am having a Facebook application that is running fine. However once i login to the facebook account, i have no choice to logout. Therefore in viewDidLoad i want to explicitly logout if already logged in. Anyone who can help me on this please provide me the necessary piece of code. Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can delete the cookies from cookie store.

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) 
{
    if ([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:@".facebook.com"]) 
    {
        [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Praveen, Now my cookies are getting deleted. But the issue here is for the first time i am able to enter Facebook after clicking on Facebook button. But after i go back to other screens and if i click on the Facebook button again i won't be able to login to Facebook to see my profile.

Comment: You should logout/delete only when you have to. Basically i am not able to understand your requirement here.